# Besser als meines – why "meines"?

Tags: declension, comparison

I found myself in a situation where I wanted to say:

> I’m a beginner, your German is better than mine!

My first attempt was wrong, because I said:

> Ich bin Anfänger, dein Deutsch ist besser als mein!

I was corrected and told to use *meines* instead of *mein.* Thinking more about it, I knew *mein* was wrong but couldn’t articulate why *meines* was right.

Is *meines* used here because you need the genitive declension of the pronoun *mein,* since it’s referring to the possessive ***my German**?*

I guess I could have avoided the pronoun, and also said:

> Ich bin Anfänger, dein Deutsch ist besser als mein Deutsch!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Mein` is one of the German possessive pronouns `mein (ich), dein (du), sein (er), ihr (sie), sein (es), unser (wir), euer (ihr), ihr (sie), Ihr (Sie)` (the words in brackets are the corresponding German personal pronouns). They (the possessive pronouns) can be inflected to act as possessive articles:

> Mein Deutsch ist besser.

But they can be also used alternatively to the noun:

> Mein(e)s ist besser als dein(e)s.

If you include the enbracketed  `e`s your language sounds more formal than without.

As another option, one could add articles:

> Das Meine ist besser als das Deine.

<sup>(This case is controversial, probably `Das meine ist besser als das deine` is correct as well, see [1](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mein_Possessivpronomen#Bedeutung2), [2](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/meine), [3](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Poss1.html) and [4](https://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/54083/sbj/das-meine-das-deine/))</sup>

But often this is expressed with the ending `-ig`:

> Das Meinige ist besser als das Deinige.

<sub>(This case is controversial, probably `Das meinige ist besser als das deinige` is correct as well, see [1](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Besonderheiten/Pron-Poss-ig3.html), [2](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Poss1.html) and [3](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/meinige))</sub>

To answer your question: `meines` is the nominative form. [Note: While it also is the genitive form, this is virtually never used (probably because it's too confusing even for native speakers)]

You can have a look at the following links to increase your understanding:

- [Possessivpronomen](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/possessivpronomen.html#deklination)
- [Possessivartikel](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/possessivartikel.html)
- [canoonet - Pronomen: Possessivpronomen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Poss1.html)

Comment: "meinem Vater" would be dative, not genitive

Comment: Yep, clinch is right: at the moment the + I want to give for "enbracketed" is cancelled out by the last example (wrong case + wrong gender)...

Comment: @clinch You're totally right; I corrected it

Comment: Sorry for butting in, Quasimodo - since your answer was accepted I felt that the error in the last bit should be rectified asap. Hope you're not offended! [I got rid of the example altogether, since I literally could not think of a neuter genitive example that a native speaker would use... a masculine example does not help here, imo.]

Comment: @Mac That's ok, I agree with you, it wasn't a good example. What do you think about `der Inhalt meines Buches`?

Comment: Das wäre zwar ein Beispiel für ein Neutrum im Genitiv - in der verkürzten Version um die es hier geht find ich es trotzdem ungewöhnlich: "Der Inhalt meines Buches ist spannender als der meines." Ich muss mich zwingen, das so stehen zu lassen, weil sich alles in mir sträubt - auch wenn es korrekt ist.

Comment: @Mac Hmm, das klingt für mich auch falsch (auch noch, wenn man in Deinem Beispiel ein `meines` durch ein `deines` ersetzt). Noch schlimmer wird es bei einigen anderen Übersetzungen aus dem Englischen... Mein Lieblingssatz: `Something will have had to be done.` wird zu `Es wird etwas getan werden müssen haben.` Laut [Quelle](http://canoo.net/blog/2014/07/22/verbformenpuzzel-fuer-den-urlaub-und-fuer-die-deheimgebliebenen/) ein Futur II eines Modalverbs mit einem Infinitiv Passiv...

Comment: Grrr, die mein/dein-Unterscheidung scheint hier irgendwie das Hauptproblem für mich zu sein, sorry... :( ... Ich finde auch, dass das Beispiel (von Deinem Fund ganz zu schweigen) falsch und grauenhaft klingt - das Ausweichen auf den Dativ ist in diesem Fall absolut die zu bevorzugende Variante...

Comment: Uhm... the words you're listing in the first sentences are actually NOT possessive pronouns but possessive adjectives/articles (depends on definition). The Articles get inflected to act as endings, not the other way around.

Comment: @Quasimodo... the Dr.Bopp explanation only makes sense if you read "done" as an adjective. I was confused at first because it interpreted it as a passive. Just thought I'd mention that. And for those interested.... http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7411/word-order-with-modal-verbs-in-complex-tenses/7413#7413

Comment: @Quasimodo... by the way, Dr. Bop doesn't seem to know himself, whether to judge it as a passive, since in present tense he does use a "werden" . The future 2 of that is "Es wird etwas getan worden sein müssen". I also just saw that the final solution contains 2 "werden", one for passive. Either that, or haben but not both.I don't know if that's a good source.

Comment: @Emanuel Please feel free to edit the answer according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not a genitive declension. It's a neuter declension. Compare:

Mein Sprachstil ist besser als deiner.

Meine Sprache ist besser als deine.

Mein Deutsch ist besser als deines.

Substituting possessive pronouns decline like adjectives, and 'Deutsch' is grammatically neuter.

Comment: Neuter what declension? There is no actual way to declense something into neuter. While it actually is the neuter declension that's used, it is **genitive** neuter what you want. So genetive declension is not wrong, but also not fully correct..

Comment: @Vogel612: It's actually nominative neuter (which looks the same as genitive)

Comment: @Mac "Dein Deutsch ist besser als **wessen?**" vs. "Dein Deutsch ist besser als **was?**" m.E. sollte es "wessen" sein.

Comment: @Vogel612: Lol, ich bin da vorhin auch erstmal eine Zeitlang mit verknoteten Gehirnwindungen dagesessen. Aber gerade die von Dir genannten Fragen führen m.E. eindeutig zu "wer". Dass "deines" natürlich auch die Antwort auf "wessen" ist, liegt daran, dass es ein Possesivpronomen ist - hat aber mit dem Fall im vorliegenden Satz nichts zu tun (sonst könnte man ja auch *"Mein Deutsch ist besser als von deinem" sagen).

Comment: @Mac meintest du nicht "Mein Deutsch ist besser als das von dir."? Und inwiefern ist "meines" kein Possesivpronomen? "Das da ist mein(e)s."

Comment: @Vogel612: Genau, das wäre die richtige Version, mit "das von dir" als Ersatz für ein Nominativ-Pronomen - mein Beispiel (mit "von deinem" als Ersatz für ein Genitiv-Pronomen) sollte verdeutlichen, dass ein Genitiv hier nicht passt. Dass "meines" und "deines" Possessivpronomen sind, hatte ich ja geschrieben. Die müssen aber, nur weil sie Besitz anzeigen (und somit immer irgendwie die Frage "wessen" beantworten), nicht zwingend im Genitiv stehen. Hier steht "meines" bzw. "deines" für "mein Deutsch" bzw. "dein Deutsch". Beantwortet wird in den Sätzen aber nicht die Frage "wessen Deutsch", [...]

Comment: [...] sondern "welches Deutsch". Genitiv wäre z.B. "Der Klang meines Deutschen ist besser als der Klang deines." Klingt natürlich furchtbar, weswegen m.E. der Genitiv so gut wie nie verwendet wird.

Answer (score 2):

The reference is to "mein Deutsch" which is neuter. If you have a phrase with "Deutsch," then the modifier "mein" does not need the neuter ending.

But when the "mein" word stands alone with "Deutsch" as the antecedent (rather than following), then "mein" needs the neuter "es" ending, and is "meines."

Another example: "Mein Deutsches Buch." (My German book.) "Deutsches" has the "es" adjectival ending, and therefore "mein" does not need it.